# SQL server 2008 r2 loading the backup to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have the following query from msdn to restore a SQL Server database backup

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DBName> FROM DISK = '<BackupFilePath>\<BackupFileName>'
GO
```

What if you want to load the backup to a new database with new name without restoring it to replace the current one?

In the interface I would select `Restore Files and Filegroups` and change the to database name then it would create a new one with the backup data in it, is this possible with a simple query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restore command above can be used to specify a new name, but when the old database still exists on the same machine you'll get an error because it will try to use the same filenames for the data. You can use the WITH MOVE clause to get around that:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestDB 
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup.BAK',
   WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.mdf',
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO 'C:\MySQLServer\testdb.ldf';
GO
```

The above example came from the MSDN documentation on the restore command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Comment: i have a back file from another machine, i copied that bak file to the root of C: Drive, how can use that back file in this command?

Comment: I'd included an example using a backup catalog, I've updated to be from a file like you require.